# How to count the number of cycles in code by hand?

Tags: performance, assembly, mips, pipeline, cpu-architecture

We are learning pipeline processing and I have an exercise, where I have to count the number of cycles a MIPS code runs for - by hand. We have the following code in `C` and `MIPS`:

```
0. for (i=0; i<10; i++)
1. som = som + a[i];

0. add $t0, $zero , $zero
1. L:
2 sll $t1 , $t2, 2
3 add $t1 , $a0 , $t1
4 lw $t1, 0($t1)
5 add $v0, $v0, $t1
6 slti $t2, $t0, 9
7 addi $t0, $t0, 1
8 bne $t2, $zero, L
9 nop
```

The code inside the loop has `7` instructions and it is executed `10` times, therefore we get `70` cycles. Then we have a stall cycles in line `5` because of the load use hazard on `$t1`. Again the code runs `10` times, thus an additional `10` cycles. In total we now have `80` cycles. Because of the `bne`, we have `9` `flushes` (not 10 because after `9` we don't come back down). Therefore, now we have `89` cycles. We then have `1` cycle for the one `NOP` and `1` cycle for the initialisation of the variable `i`. This gives us a total of `91` cycles. In the MIPS reference sheet, it says to always add 4, because of the first line of code, thus bringing our total to `95` cycles.

Assuming I'm right, which I should be, is there a faster way to count the number of cycles in any MIPS code? I could use the equation CPI = # of cycles / clock rate but assuming we're not given that information and only have the given code, is there a way? I found that if you use the following equation, you get the right answer for the given code.

```
# of cycles = 4 + # of instructions x (# of pipeline levels - 1) + # of NOPs
```

However, I'm not sure if this works in general or I got lucky with my specific example. BTW - # refers to the number of.

Comment: Line 1 does not contain an instruction, just a label.

Comment: For most modern processors, there is no simple model of how many cycles things take—many different resources may be involved. The MIPS model you are using is fairly simple, but it still generally cannot be reduced to a simple formula.

Comment: After doing that detailed analysis in the second paragraph, it should be obvious that a simple formula like that cannot work, except by accident.

Comment: Some disassemblers give you the number of cycles along with the output, saving you from manually looking it up in the manual.

Comment: You know this loop is seriously inefficient, right?  A couple instructions outside the loop could calculate an end-pointer to `bne` against, and a pointer increment instead of redoing scale + index every iteration is just obvious.  (Or increment the pointer, decrement the count and `bne` against $zero).  There's also no reason to put the sum +=  right after the load, intentionally stalling on the load hazard.  I assume that's just there to make static analysis more interesting.

Comment: Yes I agree with your point but it's an exercise to practice your ability to understand and work through a few lines of code. To that end, efficiency and the things aren't important.

Comment: Also, real classic MIPS has a branch delay slot that fully hides branch latency; it doesn't have to flush.  This code puts a NOP in the delay slot?  For real MIPS you'd put the `add $v0, $v0, $t1` there.  The loop body should be 4 instructions: lw / `addiu $t0, $t0, 4` / bne / `add` into `som`.  No stalls.

Comment: Likewise when we learned NOPs and where to use them, we first practiced with a lot of different lines of codes, and then we learned why data forwarding is a better choice than NOPs. So it's just to give the students and idea of different things.

Comment: Anyway, yes I understand that it's inefficient on purpose for the purposes of the exercise.  But wait, your cycle accounting counts 9 flushes and 1 NOP.  So does the CPU you're simulating not have [branch delay slots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot#Branch_delay_slots) after all?   That would make sense for a hypothetical RISC without branch delay slots and a branch latency of 1 cycle.  (And no branch prediction, i.e. statically predict not-taken always).

Comment: And yes, total cycles = instructions + stall cycles, assuming no cache misses.  Multi-cycle stalls can happen if you try to read the result of a slow instruction like `mult` before it's ready, though.  (And I guess +4 cycles if you want to wait for the instructions to drain from the pipeline, i.e. you're counting time after an I-cache miss that stalls fetch, and for some reason not counting as "finished" until the instruction reaches the WB stage at the end, instead of just counting as part of a flow of execution.)